# How many outfits are possible in this problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Adele owns one T-shirt and one skirt in each of the following seven colors: Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Black, Orange, and Purple. She always wants to wear a T-shirt and a skirt in different colors. If she wears a red clothing item, she also wants the second clothing item to be yellow. How many such outfits can Adele put together?

I thought like this: First don't include red and yellow, that means we have 5 colors. With every color you're able to make 5 outfits, which means we have 25 (5*5) outfits in total and when we add the two outfits we get with red and yellow we have 27 possible outfits.

Is my answer right? And are there maybe other ways of solving this problem?

Comment: Can she wear green and yellow together?  Have you accounted for this in your calculations?  "*If she wears red clothing, she wants the second clothing item to be yellow*"  Do not confuse this with "*She wears red if and only if the other item is yellow.*"  I.e.  $P\implies Q$ is not the same thing as $P\iff Q$.

Comment: Further... where did you take the statement "*She always wants to wear a T-shirt and a skirt in different colors*" into account?  In your $5\times 5$, did you not allow for the possibility of Green with Green?  Are green and green different colors from each other?

Comment: Does that mean that she wears red only with yellow but she can for example wear blue with red? So if we also consider that the outfits have to be different colors we have to do 6*5=30 and +1 which means 31 possible outfits?

Comment: No, that means that if at least one of the outfit pieces is red then the other must be yellow, but the reverse is not necessary... she could wear yellow with blue or blue with yellow, or yellow with green etc...  As for the calculation, yes we have six colors (*including yellow*) that aren't red.  Choose one of those six for the top, and then choose a different one (*five choices remain*) for the bottom.  Lastly... include the *two* outfits (red top yellow bottom, vs red bottom yellow top*) that were possible that included red.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you